# Doubts about Shared Memory space between processes

Tags: operating-system

I am new to the subject Operating Systems.
Started studying Operating Systems recently.

I am stuck with some abstraction which I am unable to catch a hold of.

During studying interprocess communication, I read that shmget() allocates a memory Segment and returns an integer called shmid.

As far as I understood,this shared memory Segment will be used for communication between two different processes,let's say process P1 and P2 respectively.

But it's written that before any process can access that shared memory Segment created by shmget(),the process must attach this shared memory Segment in its address space.

I couldn't understand that what is actually meant by **attaching the shared memory Segment to the address space of a process.**

I meant isn't it enough for a process to just know about the starting address of the shared memory Segment to access it?

And also what actually is happening when the **shared memory is getting attached to the address space of a process? And whose address is it...which is being returned by the function shmat()?**

Answer (score 0):

> During studying interprocess communication, I read that shmget() allocates a memory Segment and returns an integer called shmid.

Most likely, your processes don't need to communicate that way. An application often uses several threads belonging to the same process instead and simply share heap data by passing pointers around. In all cases, it is the threads that are responsible to manage concurrent accesses and race conditions for the data. I haven't read about it but I'd say shmid is an id that threads of another process use to identify which segment of memory they want to attach. The OS keeps track of shared segments giving each segment an id.

> I couldn't understand that what is actually meant by attaching the shared memory Segment to the address space of a process.

If one process requests a shared memory segment, other processes haven't notified the kernel that they also use it. One process needs to create the segment and save the id. The processes who want to share it need to use that id to notify the kernel that they also want to acess that shared memory.

> And also what actually is happening when the shared memory is getting attached to the address space of a process? And whose address is it...which is being returned by the function shmat()?

Each process has a PCB that informs the kernel on the virtual memory that is allocated to it. Attaching memory to the process means adding that memory segment to the list of memory allocated to the process to avoid a page fault when it attempts an access. If the process doesn't notify the kernel then the kernel will kill it after realising that it isn't permitted to access the data (because it isn't in its adress space yet).

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't understand that what is actually meant by attaching the shared memory Segment to the address space of a process

Simply it means, updating the page table of the process so it can map it's virtual addresses to the physical address of the owner process of the shared memory.

we can understand it by using the concept of paging.
so let it be a abstraction for now.

> And also what actually is happening when the shared memory is getting attached to the address space of a process? And whose address is it...which is being returned by the function shmat()?

when a process, say P1 want's to share it's memory, it must create a shared memory region. for that it calls shmget() syscall containing few parameters. if it's successful then shmget() returns an identifier, say `52`.

now if another process P2 want's to use that shared memory created by P1, it must call shmat() and mention that identifier (in this case `52`) and if it's successful it's returned a pointer from where P2 now can read or write or do both.

1. P2 now can modify the shared memory region. ex. write something on it.
2. it's the address space of P1.